# Virtual Box shows virtual size as 59.7 GB but actual size is 6.84 GB. Need to expand the root to use full 60GB

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

I was trying to install software into a CentOS Linux. It shows that I don't have enough space. When I do `df -h` I get the following result

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  6.7G  6.7G     0 100% /
devtmpfs                 1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.4G  8.7M  1.4G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                497M  157M  341M  32% /boot
tmpfs                    282M     0  282M   0% /run/user/0
```

Then I checked the Virtual Box settings it shows that Virtual size is 59.7 GB but the actual size is 6.84 GB

How do I increase the size to 59.7 GB?

Comment: probably you've partitioned the disk incorrectly. The hard disk size is 59.7GB but the root partition is only 6.7GB, the remaining is just blank space. Run `fdisk -l` to see

Comment: Yes, you are right. How do I increase the root partition to 59.7GB? when I run `fdisk -l` I get this @phuclv 


`Disk /dev/sda: 64.0 GB, 63962087424 bytes, 124925952 sectors
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048    16777215     7875584   8e  Linux LVM`

Answer (score 0):

From your comment /dev/sda2 is around ~8GB (since it looks like fdisk uses 1KiB sector, but I'm not sure about that)

```
/dev/sda: 64.0 GB, 63962087424 bytes, 124925952 sectors

Device      Boot    Start       End         Sectors     Size    Id Type
/dev/sda1   *       2048        1026047     512000      83      Linux
/dev/sda2           1026048     16777215    7875584     8e      Linux LVM
```

Just run gparted to resize /dev/sda2 to the end of the hard drive, and then resize your LVM partition. For more information about resize LVM partition read [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/q/196125/253474)

Comment: thanks for the comment. I need to expand it 60 GB, the article that you linked shows "How to shrink" Is there a way to expand?

Comment: Hi @phuclv, I did run the following, it does seem to have given another 8% free. Here is what I did


`[root@localhost ~]# lvextend -l 100%VG /dev/mapper/centos-root
  Size of logical volume centos/root changed from 6.67 GiB (1707 extents) to 6.71 GiB (1717 extents).
  Logical volume root successfully resized.`

Here is the result
`[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  6.7G  5.5G  1.3G  82% /` Still wondering how do get to use the 60 GB, which is not showing in any of the disk usage?

Comment: @truthtriumphs did you resize /dev/sda2 as I said? Because `6.67 GiB (1707 extents) to 6.71 GiB (1717 extents)` looks like the partition is still the same size, so LVM can't resize it any bigger than that

Comment: Thanks!! I missed that step. I am trying to resize it

Comment: @phclv I don't see a /dev/sda2 patition. Here is the result of `df -h` command  

`/dev/mapper/centos-root  6.7G  5.6G  1.2G  83% /
devtmpfs                 1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.4G  8.7M  1.4G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                497M  157M  341M  32% /boot
tmpfs                    282M     0  282M   0% /run/user/0` Kindly forgive me I am just learning how Linux does partitions

Comment: of course you can't see /dev/sda2 if you run `df -h` because it isn't mounted anywhere. It's just a container for LVM to store its partitions (which is the /dev/mapper you saw above). You need to use a disk partitioner like gparted to resize the container first before you can store more things in it

Comment: Thanks @phuclv I am connecting via Putty. I did install gparted when type in `gparted` I get the following result `[root@localhost ~]# gparted

(gpartedbin:12004): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:` I did try using parted. How do I fix this?

Comment: if you can setup display forwarding then you can use GUI apps through SSH. Otherwise you need a CLI partitioner, but I've never partitioned a disk from command line so I'm not sure about that

Comment: Thanks @phuclv. I managed to use X11 to forward to my Windows client where I am using my Putty. I am able to get GUI programs from Putty SSH. For e.g if type i  `[root@localhost ~]# libreoffice` I get the LiberOffice program in Windows. But when I type `gparted` I get the following error. `[root@localhost ~]# gparted
/usr/sbin/gpartedbin: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/gpartedbin: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib17SignalProxyNormal13connect_impl_EbON4sigc9slot_baseEb`

Comment: @truthtriumphs to resize the 8e LVM container from command line you can use `sfdisk`. See [Resize extended partition lvm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/379549/44425)

Comment: Thanks @phuclv. I ended up deleting everything and recreating another VM...